# Games HelixJump in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity-container

I have an error in the code.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
UIManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:13)
```

[image]

I hope the ball bounces and counts the points up in the score.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)